# use fingerprint login

Tags: 16.04, scanner

I just got a Lenovo ideapad 520, which includes a fingerprint scanner. It works fine for Windows, but when using Fingerprint GUI it simply doesn't detect the device. So I'm assuming I need a driver for this device, but I can't find any drivers online.

Does anyone know how to make this work in ubuntu 16.014?